# Using Beautiful Soup to find specific class

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use Beautiful Soup to scrape housing price data from Zillow.

I get the web page by property id, eg. http://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/18429834_zpid/

When I try the `find_all()` function, I do not get any results:

```
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class":"home-summary-row"})
```

However, if I take the HTML and cut it down to just the bits I want, eg.:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class=" status-icon-row for-sale-row home-summary-row">
        </div>
        <div class=" home-summary-row">
            <span class=""> $1,342,144 </span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get 2 results, both `<div>`s with the class `home-summary-row`. So, my question is, why do I not get any results when searching the full page?

---

Working example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

zpid = "18429834"
url = "http://www.zillow.com/homes/" + zpid + "_zpid/"
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
#html = '<html><body><div class=" status-icon-row for-sale-row home-summary-row"></div><div class=" home-summary-row"><span class=""> $1,342,144 </span></div></body></html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")

results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class":"home-summary-row"})
print(results)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [W3.org Validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zillow.com%2Fhomes%2Ffor_sale%2F18429834_zpid%2F), there are a number of issues with the HTML such as stray closing tags and tags split across multiple lines. For example:

```
<a 
href="http://www.zillow.com/danville-ca-94526/sold/"  title="Recent home sales" class=""  data-za-action="Recent Home Sales"  >
```

This kind of markup can make it much more difficult for BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML.

You may want to try running something to clean up the HTML, such as removing the line breaks and trailing spaces from the end of each line. BeautifulSoup can also clean up the HTML tree for you:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
tree = BeautifulSoup(bad_html)
good_html = tree.prettify()
```

Comment: That did the trick. I tried looking for missing tags by eye, but there was too much code. W3.org Validator is a great resource I was not aware of. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Your HTML is *non-well-formed* and in cases like this, choosing the right parser is crucial. In [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc), there are currently 3 available HTML parsers which *work and handle broken HTML differently*:

- `html.parser` (built-in, no additional modules needed)
- `lxml` (the fastest, requires `lxml` to be installed)
- `html5lib` (the most lenient, requires `html5lib` to be installed)

The [Differences between parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) documentation page describes the differences in more detail. In your case, to demonstrate the difference:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
>>> 
>>> zpid = "18429834"
>>> url = "http://www.zillow.com/homes/" + zpid + "_zpid/"
>>> response = requests.get(url)
>>> html = response.content
>>> 
>>> len(BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib").find_all('div', attrs={"class":"home-summary-row"}))
0
>>> len(BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").find_all('div', attrs={"class":"home-summary-row"}))
3
>>> len(BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml").find_all('div', attrs={"class":"home-summary-row"}))
3
```

As you can see, in your case, both `html.parser` and `lxml` do the job, but `html5lib` does not.

Comment: @RobBenz make sure you have `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` import - I saw the other answer suggesting `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup`, which is not good - this is the BeautifulSoup version 3 import - this version is quite outdated and not maintained.

Comment: @RobBenz also, if you need only the summary elements, you can use [`SoupStrainer`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) to speed up parsing and parse only the desired elements instead of the whole tree.

Answer (score 7):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

zpid = "18429834"
url = "http://www.zillow.com/homes/" + zpid + "_zpid/"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "home-summary-row"})

print g_data[1].text

#for item in g_data:
#        print item("span")[0].text
#        print '\n'
```

I got this working too -- but it looks like someone beat me to it.

going to post anyways.

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. Simply using a different parser made it work. I'm curious if this is faster than prettifying the HTML before searching. I will have to test this. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, sorry for typo in first line, copy & paste error; fixed now